# SSRS with Oracle

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, oracle-sqldeveloper, birt, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on connecting Oracle database with SSRS. Previously I was using BIRT for reporting, and now I have to use SSRS. I just want to know if just an Oracle Client set up at the server is enough or anything else is a basic requirement for this change. Since BIRT reports have been using Oracle too, I thing the setup is good. But I keep getting a "no listener" error, and a "could not resolve the connect identifier specified
" error too. Since the DB setup was already there using BIRT, should there be any extra setup that is expected. Please advice how to go about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All you should need is the provider so SSRS can talk to Oracle.  See [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220591.aspx).

Note the remarks: *"Before you can connect an Oracle data source, the system administrator must have installed the version of the .NET Data Provider for Oracle that supports retrieving data from the Oracle database. This data provider must be installed on the same computer as Report Builder and also on the report server. "*